# Issue Configuring Eclipse with Cordova

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

After setting up Eclipse with Cordova, I am having an issue getting the IDE to run a simple app on the emulator.  I have it set to use the latest version of the android SDK, and I have cleaned the project.  Yet, I still get this error:

Application package 'AndroidManifest.xml' must have a minimum of 2 segments.

Under the XML File, the package node reads as "**PACKAGE**".  Any ideas on how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like cordova actually switched up their docs a bit.  I was supposed to run the create batch file instead of opening root as a project